# MSF4J: wso2 access service provider User Access Token Expiry Time

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am writing a JWTAccessTokenBuilder for wso2is based on the msf4j. Now I want to use the user access token expiry time configured for a specific service provider and not the global configured time, which can be accessed with getApplicationAccessTokenValidityPeriodInSeconds(). Is there a way to get the time for the service provider by API?

Comment: Can you try with OAuth2Util.getSpTokenExpiryTimeConfig() by passing consumer key and tenant id?

Comment: This is available by default from IS-5.4.0.

Comment: I can not find this in the last version (4.4.29) and in the version I found in the internet https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/util/OAuth2Util.java,it is marked as Deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the soloution
OAuth2Util.getAuthzRequestContext().getValidityPeriod()
The result is in milliseconds.